# Convert UTC ISO string date to Unix timestamp

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, utc, google-sheets-formula

I have this UTC date in a Google spreadsheet: `2018-10-18T08:55:13Z` and would like to convert it to Unix timestamp (`1539852913`). I tried this formula, but it's unable to recognize the timevalue:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1;1;10)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1;12;8))
```

If I can get a valid date and time, I can use this formula to convert to Unix timestamp:

```
=(A1-$C$1)*86400
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: do you have proceeding 0 for the day and the month?  Ie January first is 2018-01-01 or 2018-1-1 or 2018-01-1 or 2018-1-01?  it makes a difference on possible ways to pull your date from the string

Answer (score 4):

Simpler:

```
=86400*(left(substitute(A1,"T"," "),19))-2209161600
```

Replaces `T` with space and cuts off `Z`, leaving what's left recognisable as date and time in arithmetical calculations. Convert day and time index into seconds and adjust for the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date has proceeding zeros for single digit days and month, pull each date string part and drop it into the `DATE` formula as follows:

```
Year
=LEFT(A1,4)

Month
=MID(A1,6,2)

Day
=MID(A1,9,2)

Use the date formula
=DATE(year,month,day)
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))
```

A similar process can be used for TIME

```
Hour
=MID(A1,12,2)

Minutes
=MID(A1,15,2)

Seconds
=MID(A1,18,2)

Time
=TIME(Hour,Minutes,Seconds)
=TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))
```

1)  There are other methods

2)  The formulas will need to be adapted if you do not have leading 0 for each unit. In that case you would need to use FIND to identify the position of key characters and measure the distance between them to determine if there was a single digit unit or double digit unit.

Since the date is the integer part (left of the decimal) represents the number of days since 1900/01/01 (with that date being 1) and decimal portion represents time in terms of fraction of a day, to get a full date and time, you would add the date formula to the time formula as follows:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))
```

Comment: Whole datestamp would be:

=DATE( LEFT(A1,4), MID(A1,6,2), MID(A1,9,2) ) + TIME( MID(A1,12,2), MID(A1,15,2), MID(A1,18,2) )

(NB The original has A1, 6, 2) for both day and month)

Comment: @Dnaaz thanks, updated formula and added a chunk at the end.